# Maven can't find parent POM

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to build a maven project, but I have encountered problem.

pom has specified parent pom and maven can't find it. I actually have the parent pom, but I don't know where to place it or what should I do so maven knows about.

I'm new to maven so sorry if my question is stupid.

Comment: We can try to help you if you show us what you already have (relevant pom.xml content, project structure, ...) and what you mean by "maven can't find it".

Comment: Your question is not specific enough, it could be due to so much different issues...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the parent pom, you could try installing it.

When you run `mvn install` on a module the resulting artifact will be placed in your repository, so that it can be used from other modules.

Comment: Tip: temporarily remove <modules> section to prevent chicken-and-egg when you install the parent pom first time.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Netbeans, I ran **-N versions:update-child-modules** in Run Maven/Goals.

It worked!  It took 5 minutes to build but, it did build the project, and that's the first time that it has.

Comment: This worked for me. It allowed me to discover a typing error on the parent pom version number.

Comment: Worked for me also. From command prompt: `mvn -N versions:update-child-modules`

Answer (score 0):

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html Example 1 and Example 2 are for Inheritance that can be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the different POM in the project. They do not have the same version.

For example if you have:

```
MyProject / EAR ..... MyProject / WEB .....
```

you need to have the same version in three POM

Comment: how does this improve the previously accepted answer ?

Answer (score -1):

Same error for me.I resolved by updating the project with a new POM file(someone form my team accidently deleted it).